# what's is the correct way to decode my json

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, decode

Sorry Guys I am racking my brains here. New to swift just learning and can't decode below starred

its the response from print out after successfully receiving request

Can you help please with below error - I can see response just can't decode it

"failure(SwiftClient.NetworkError.decodingError)"

thanks in advance for your help

Alan

```
Response print out *****************

("{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"username\":\"johncase\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$tyFnx6.7yR/66QHDlySOf3PG9RIpusOEIGmDCRkOI9ZX888rkpy\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$3iR3SdEjkVZ5w7/666dZwOvwN7ohqd1L0jDt30k/nmSt0888VyLfe\"}]}")

struct MyData model**********
// MARK: - Welcome
struct MyData: Codable {
   let data: Account
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Account: Codable {
    let id, username, password: String
}
************************

getallaccount function in web service ***********************
 func getAllAccounts(token: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[MyData], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        
            guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.5.22:5000/users/getUpdated/") else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
       
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue((token), forHTTPHeaderField: "gfg_token_header_key")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
           
         
        
           guard let accounts = try? JSONDecoder().decode([MyData].self, from: data) else {
           completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            return
           }
           
            completion(.success(accounts))
            
            
            
        }.resume()
        
        
    }
 *********************************************
```

Comment: paste your response in here: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: the problem seems to be the `\"` i.e. the backslash before each quotation mark. If they appear as is in the response, you have to filter them out.

Comment: NEVER use `try?` (with the question mark) unless you know how do debug. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`, and print the `error` in the `catch`. And `let data: Account` should be then `let data: [Account]` I guess, since the API is returning an array of accounts, and `[MyData].self` should be `MyData.self`...

Comment: response from postman is {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "username": "myusername1",
            "password": "$2a$10$tyFnx6.7yR/MY3oQHDlyrrrrrG9RIpusOEIGmDCRkOI9ZXzV3rkpy"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "username": "myusername",
            "password": "$2a$10$3iR3SdEjkVZ5w7/lgrrrwOvwN7ohqd1L0jDt30k/nmSt0h47VyLfe"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: The use of `try?` discards the informative error object. Use `try` instead, and `catch` the error. It will point out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example you posted:

```
("{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"username\":\"johncase\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$tyFnx6.7yR/66QHDlySOf3PG9RIpusOEIGmDCRkOI9ZX888rkpy\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$3iR3SdEjkVZ5w7/666dZwOvwN7ohqd1L0jDt30k/nmSt0888VyLfe\"}]}")
```

Looks like `Data` has an array of `Account` while the `Data` itself is not an array. Change your code like this and try

```
struct MyData: Codable {
   let data: [Account]
}
struct Account: Codable {
    let id, username, password: String
}

...

let accounts = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyData.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks Guys the array adjust worked from Suyash. Thanks to you all for your help